# button click in html for jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I have the following coding in JSP which work when a JSP page is loaded:

```
<%
String sportugues = request.getParameter("port");
String senglish = request.getParameter("engl");
String sfuncgram = request.getParameter("funcgram");
//Integer snsyn = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("nsyninp"));

Usuario usu = new Usuario();
usu.setPortugues(sportugues);
usu.setEnglish(senglish);
usu.setFuncgram(sfuncgram);
//usu.setNsyn(snsyn); 

UsuarioDao usudDao = new UsuarioDao();
usudDao.cadastroStudyAlfaDireita(usu);
%>
```

But I want it to work only when I click a HTML button like:

```
<button onclick="">JSP Command</button>
```

The button and the JSP coding must be in the same JSP page.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code that you need to load when click in a condition that check `isButtonClick`, then assign to `onClick` a function to update it

```
<c:set var="isButtonClicked" value="false" />

<c:if test="${isButtonClicked}">
  <%
  String sportugues = request.getParameter("port");
  String senglish = request.getParameter("engl");
  String sfuncgram = request.getParameter("funcgram");
  //Integer snsyn = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("nsyninp"));

  Usuario usu = new Usuario();
  usu.setPortugues(sportugues);
  usu.setEnglish(senglish);
  usu.setFuncgram(sfuncgram);
  //usu.setNsyn(snsyn); 

  UsuarioDao usudDao = new UsuarioDao();
  usudDao.cadastroStudyAlfaDireita(usu);
  %>
</c:if>

<button onClick="function(){<c:set var="isButtonClicked" value="${!isButtonClicked}"} />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be in JSP. What language is your code?